# Bootstrap won't display default icons and font awesome icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've changed the default bootstrap.css file, and when I use default icons, it doesn't display anything, and when I use font-awesome icons, it's just a square. This is my bootstrap.css:

http://pastebin.com/XveCZ1a5

Comment: here's an fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Jx6/

Comment: Just show us the lines you've changed. Don't make us go through 1000's lines of code and guess.

Comment: @Adrift Huh, they don't work in the navbar. I've changed navbar css codes.

Comment: @Adrift Copied the css, and it still doesn't work. I've tried clearing cache in chrome too.

Comment: @Adrift I understand, but it still doesn't work, I've tried reloading the site and clearing cache in the browser, but it still appears the same.

Comment: @Adrift It works now, could you post an answer so I could accept it? Thanks once again. Also, I've noticed the font-awesome icons doesn't work. I've included the css..

Comment: @core_m: Where did you include the CSS?

Comment: @Adrift In the html file, included it like this `<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`.

Comment: @Adrift Nope, no errors. It just appears as a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the Bootstrap build system where it winds up creating corrupted fonts.

I can't find the actual bug tracker link that I originally read it in but if you look around SO you'll see similar problems from others all related to the same thing.

The easiest way to fix this is to recompile the files and get the new font files. Pretty sure you can just do it via the customizer on the official site.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: awesome, glad I could be of assistance :D